# Oracle: Update based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update a column of table based on a condition. It should check if the value exists in other table, if exists then value from other table will be used else value from same table will be used.

```
Update table1
Set column1=(select t2.alias||’@email.com’ as new_name
From table2 t2, table1 t1, table3 t3
Where t1.id=t2.id
And t1.id=t3.id

Else if
Select t2.alias is null or t2.id is null 
then column1= select t1.id||’@email.com’ as new_name
```

Any suggestions on this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Update table1
Set column1 = (select (case when t2.alias is not null and t2.id is not null then t2.alias
                            else t1.id
                       end) ||'@email.com' as new_name
               From table1 t1 left outer join
                    table2 t2
                    on t1.id=t2.id
              );
```

I removed `table3` because it does not seem to be used.  With `left join` is won't even be filtering any results.

Answer (score 0):

By leaving out the "insert" half of the `merge` statement, you can make it into a strictly `update` statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t
USING(
  SELECT t2.id, t2.Alias
  FROM   table2 t2
  JOIN   table1 t1
    ON   t1.id = t2.id
    AND  t1.Alias <> t2.Alias
) tu
on( tu.id = t.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  update set t.Alias = tu.Alias;
```

The query will return only those existing values from table2 that differ from table1. To make it exactly match your requirement (update table1 if *any* value exists in table2) then remove the line `AND t1.Alias <> t2.Alias`, but why update a field to the same value it already has?